# Encoding in pandas

Tags: python, csv, encoding, pandas, decoding

I have a csv file that is encoded in `GB2312`. I had successfully read it into pandas.dataframe by the option `encoding = 'GB2312'`. However, when I opened the file in STATA (and did quite some manual editing) and saved it back in csv, I failed to open it in pandas. I got the following error message:

```
'gb2312' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 2044: incomplete multibyte sequence
```

So it seems there was some characters in the file that cannot be decoded (Indeed I can read in the first couple lines with no problem). Python has an `'ignore'` option for decoding strings, but I don't know how to impose that option for `read_csv`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the problem may lie with Stata.  Make a copy of the Stata-saved file and try cutting it down in size until you zero in on the part that causes the error.  Then compare that to the original file.  Perhaps you can figure out whether Stata is messing the file up when reading it.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I figured out what the problem is. Basically STATA has a limit for strings up to str244. So when I save csv from STATA, some characters were cut in half, the encoding of which cannot be recognized by python. I don't have a solution for it yet. I did some quite tedious editing in STATA which I certainly do not want to replicate in python.

Comment: @ZhenSun, maybe this is too late already, but Stata prints out the script version of any manual editing you do (something like `replace var2 = 28 in 4`). If you have the log of your manual edit saved somewhere, it shouldn't be difficult to automatically convert `replace var2 = 28 in 4` and the like into pandas code - just parse this string for the arguments to your custom pandas replacement function.

Comment: @cd98, Thanks for the comments. The Stata editings are all in script version. There were just too many changes to replicate in python. I don't know how the commands in Stata and python can be automatically converted...

Comment: @ZhenSun : as long as there's some pattern in the changes, I think someone in Stackoverflow might come up with an automatic conversion (I'm happy to give it a try myself).

Comment: @cd98, Thanks for the suggestion. If there is already a coded `automatic conversion`, I can post the full code in Stata. Otherwise, translating the codes may be too much work.

Comment: @ZhenSun : it depends on how many different command you used. If your script is just `replace` done hundreds of times, then it shouldn't be so difficult to do, since you just need to parse a couple of arguments (I had to do something similar a while ago). Maybe post it as a different question and see if people respond?